# Vue.js3 Is there a way to use slots in App.vue and use them in views?

Tags: vue.js, layout, routes, slots

I am building a small app with vue3 and I would like to use slots to change things in the header. I defined the general layout in App.vue and have 2 slots there to change the layout depending on the active view.

I can surely do this using variables and state management but kinda wished I could do it with named slots so I can easily put components or anything inside the slot.

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="sidebar">
    main navigation
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="header">
      top bar with searchbox etc, SLOT: I need to change the page title
      SLOT: sometimes I need a menu in here
    </div>
    <div class="content">
       <router-view />
    </div>
</div>
```

I had no success using named slots + `<base-layout>`

Am I approaching this completely wrong ? I'm pretty sure Nuxt has something like this out of the box. I see online there are solutions using component layouts but I'm unsure how to do the routing with that